# Access grandchild of a variable (parent.child.grandchild) without dots and one pair of brackets

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas, square-bracket

I'm building a canvas-related class with a kind of conversion table. The conversion table can be edited by the user. (Isn't really relevant, but maybe you want to know why):

```
cLayout = function(option) {
    //obtaining the canvas (el) here
    this.setup = function(option) {
        t=this.table;
        for (var p in t)
        {
            el[t[p][0]] = option[p]||t[p][1]
        }
    }
    this.setup(option)
}

cLayout.prototype.table = {
    width:[['style']['width'],"100%"],
    height:['style'['height'],"100%"],
    bg:[['style']['backgroundColor'],""],
    position:[['style']['position'],"absolute"],
    left:['style'['left'],"0px"],
    top:['style'['left'],"0px"]
}
```

Example:

```
var b = new cLayout({left:'10%',width:'90%'})
```

---

Real question:

Normally, I'd use `el['style']['width']` to set el.style.width.
But I want to use `el[something]` without the second pair of brackets: I want the property name to be completely variable (I also want to be able to set `el['innerHTML']`). So, is there a way to get a grandchild by using `a[b]`, without using `a[b][c]`?

P.S. Of course, I don't want to use eval.

Comment: This `[['style']['width'],"100%"]` does not make sense. It will try to access the `width` property of the `['style']` array, which is `undefined`. So what you get is `[undefined, "100%"]`. Similar for `['style'['left'],"0px"]`.

Comment: I know. It's what I'd like to have, but it doesn't work of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible. If you have nested objects, you cannot just skip a level.

You could write a helper function though, which takes a string like `"child.grandchild"` and sets the corresponding property:

```
function setProp(obj, prop, val) {
    var parts = prop.split('.');
    while(parts.length > 1) {
        obj = obj[parts.shift()];
    }
    obj[parts.shift()] = val;
}
```

(You should also test whether a certain property is available.)

Then your code could look like:

```
var cLayout = function(option) {
    //obtaining the canvas (el) here
    this.setup = function(option) {
        for(var p in this.table) {
            setProp(el, this.table[p][0], option[p]||t[p][1]);
        }
    }
    this.setup(option)
}

cLayout.prototype.table = {
    width:['style.width',"100%"],
    height:['style.height',"100%"],
    //...
}
```